# PHP number_format not working as expected

Tags: php

PHP 7.3.4

When I use

```
$val = '1,234.00';
echo number_format($val, 2, '.', '');
```

I get

```
1   (desired output is 1234.00)
```

If I do

```
$val = '1,234.00';
$val = str_replace([',', '$'], '', $val);
echo number_format($val, 2, '.', '');
```

I get

```
1234.00
```

Why doesn't the first one work? What am I missing about the number_format function?

Comment: number_format() takes a float as the 1st argument, you're giving it an already formatted string.

Comment: `number_format(float $num, . . . )`  When that string is converted to a `float` it is `1` because it truncates invalid characters and everything after. See `echo (float)'1,234.00';`

Comment: Na, do not float the $val. Use `$val = str_replace(',', '', $val);` before `number_format()`.

Comment: @cottton I didn't say to `float` it, that just shows what it does.

Comment: Suggest to turn all error reports on, php will show you "Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 important points which need to understand about `number_format()`

- number_format() takes a float as the 1st argument. If string given than convert it in Integer/Float. If found any character in string take the integer part before that character.
- return a number with grouped thousands that means a string.

First check the datatype

```
$a = 1234; // integer
$a = 1234.00; // float
$a = "1234.00"; // string and we can use it as int/float
$a = "1,234.00"; // string but we can't use as int/float because of comma
```

In first example

```
$val = '1,234.00';
echo number_format($val, 2, '.', '');
```

The type of $val is string. So number_format() takes only the int/float part of string and when found any character trim that number. So taking only 1 and  you are getting 1.00.
Let's try with

```
$val = '12,34.00';
echo number_format($val, 2, '.', '');
$val = '12Z34.00'; // also check with this
echo number_format($val, 2, '.', '');
```

And you will get the result 12.00 for both.You can also check with

```
$val = 12,34;
echo number_format($val, 2, '.', '');
```

And you will get

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','

That means it not assuming $val as a string. Lets we check with a string without **','** and we will again use `number_format()` with converted number.

```
$val = "1234.00";
echo $first = number_format($val, 2, '.', ',');
echo $second = number_format($first, 2, '.', ',');
```

the output of above example is:

> 1,234.00
>
> 1.00

So $val work like a float number and in $first we are getting a string number and for $second it is separate again with comma and the output is `1.00`. So if you have a string with comma, first you need to remove comma from that string then format that using `number_format()`